# Simulate another tap within @IBAction

Tags: ios, swift3

```
@IBAction func submitButtonDown(_ sender: AnyObject) {

if !self.arrivalCityField.hasText {

    singleTon.shouldNotSubmitForm()

}

if singleTon.canSubmitForm() {
    self.endEditing(true)
    self.submitButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)  //Ends up looping     forever, I need this to run after the current execution has finished but only once... (that is tap once, wait, then programatically tap another time.
}
```

Is there a way to simulate another touchup on the same button right after the `IBAction` function has finished running?

I have tried using `GCD` but it keeps looping...

Comment: You just call the code you need, no need to simulate the tap.

Comment: My only problem is that a variable that gets triggered within this function doesn't change until the function has finished running, I need to simulate  a tap right after the function has finished running,  otherwise it ends up running simultaneously with the original tap...

Comment: I suggest you re-think what you are doing. Timing dependent operations almost certainly mean you have the wrong approach. It sounds like the code that changes the variable should then do whatever needs to be done, possibly by a completionHandler closure or something

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking a completion closure should be in order, but is it possible to attach one to an IBAction?

Comment: @IBAction is just a signal to Xcode that you can link an action in interface builder to a specific function. Whatever you write inside that function is up to you. You can use a delegate pattern or store a closure in a property to invoke from your function.

Comment: Thank you Paulw11, will try that out